# onchange not calling function on a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue where a function is not being called onchange. However, I did set up a onmouseover event to just to see if the function can be called at all. onchange doesn't work, but onmouseover does. Any ideas why onchange doesn't work after selecting a date. When the date gets selected, the field does in fact change.

```
<div class="sectionData"> 
     <span class="cell"> 
      <mcdatepicker id="txtIssueReported_date" name="txtIssueReported_date" title="#mastercontrol.translate.Adaptimmune_TRANS_CDEV.T2_L11#" label="#mastercontrol.translate.Adaptimmune_TRANS_CDEV.T2_L11#" alt="T2 Date Issue Reported" maxdate="0" daterangeerrortext="#mastercontrol.translate.Adaptimmune_TRANS_CDEV.C_L11#" onblur="SetFieldsRequired();" onmouseover="SetFieldsRequired();" onchange="SetFieldsRequired();" onkeydown="SP_ContinueAutoSave(false);"> 
      </mcdatepicker> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What particular datepicker library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `onchange` event to be fired, the element in question must change value AND then loose focus. Try for example changing the date, and then selected a different input field.

Comment: Yeeeahh... Well, that was completely bush league. I can't believe I did that... Might help if the form knows the field changed...

I put this blur before the change.

Answer (score 0):

The blur happened before the change. Thanks -VKK